# jQuery: Check if a user refresh a page himself

Tags: jquery, refresh

Good morning everybody;

I am checking if a user has refresh the page by himself:

```
$('.question').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "NextQuestion.php",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {

    window.location = '<?php echo $URL; ?>';

    }
    });
    });
```

The above code was a refresh by clicking a link class is "question", if the person did not click that link and refreshed the page by himself it should mark an alert, what I am lookin for is:

if a person has clicked the link ==> page will be refreshed and will not show any error

if a person refresh by pressing F5 or other keys,... ==> page will be refreshed and will show an error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be done is to use some sort of state, in this case, I used client-side.

```
$('.question').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NextQuestion.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.cookie('clicked', 'yes');
            window.location = '<?php echo $URL; ?>';
        }
    });
});
```

Then test:

```
if(!$.removeCookie('clicked')) {
    alert('You refreshed your page');
}
```

The code example uses the jQuery cookie plugin.

If the `'clicked'` cookie is set, then they clicked; otherwise they refreshed. This isn't completely foolproof; it is possible to click, then navigate away before navigation completes, and then come back. You can set a expiration time if you are worried about that, but that is the <1% use case.

Comment: well it says:TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

Comment: @AbuRayane, like I said, this uses jQuery cookie: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/. If you don't want to use jQuery cookie (though you are already using jQuery), you'll have to create your own cookie functions.

Comment: I am using jQuery, not jQuery cookie, what is the difference?? if I would like to stay using jQuery, how can we create a cookie?